# IIS doesn't render the ASP.net MVC view. It lists down all files and folders inside the physical path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10

I'm trying to host `ASP.net MVC` application on `IIS 10` (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - Azure) 
I hosted a default ASP.net MVC project on it. But when I request the page, It's listing down all the files and folders in the browser. 
I tried by disabling `Directory Browsing` then it gives `403.14` error.
the same project is working fine on IIS version 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2)

How can I resolve this issue?
are there any special configurations to be done on IIS or the project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On the server role and features, can you check if these options on the image below are selected?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the below code in your web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

also, make sure you enable the iis .net feature and the application pool is using the right version of .net.